# Determinant and spectral decomposition of matrix with known elements

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I am interested in studying the determinant and the spectral decomposition of a matrix which is close to being singular. More in particular, the matrix elements are of the form
$$
 a_{tr} = \frac{1}{t+r}, \quad t,r=1,\dots,T
$$
and I would like to complement my numerical analysis, whose details I am reporting below, with some analytical results, but so far I have been unable to do so. To be more precise, I would like to (ideally) have an analytical results for the eigenvalues and the determinant of this matrix.

By numerical analysis I already found that its eigenvalues are exponentially decreasing, with an exponent that for the small eigenvalues scales linearly but actually (and it becomes evident at large eigenvalues only) it scales quadratically with $t$. Also its condition number explodes exponentially as we increase $T$.

Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: It's a special case of [Cauchy matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix), similar to a [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix). It's also a [Gramian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, it was very helpful! If I may ask a following question, I am finding many useful results for the Hilbert matrix, which has the (i,j) element as i+j-1 rather than i+j. Do you happen to know if results are also known for my case, or should I derive them from Cauchy?

Comment: You should be able to prove that $\det(H_n)=\binom{2n}{n}\det(A_n)$, where $A_n$ is your matrix and $H_n$ the Hilbert matrix. But you'll probably need to derive this from the Cauchy determinant, indeed. There are a few statements about $A_n$, as well as the more general $1/(i+j+\alpha)$ [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975779) (where it's mentioned that it has also been called the Hilbert matrix). I didn't find much more so far.

Comment: Thanks again! Besides the determinant and the inverse matrix elements, unfortunately so far I have not been able to find much about close, explicit formulae for the eigenvalues, or at least their behavior, both for the Cauchy and Hilbert matrices. Do you happen to have any further suggestion regarding this point?

Comment: There are questions absout eigenvalues of [Cauchy](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138475/what-is-known-about-the-spectrum-of-a-cauchy-matrix) and [Hilbert](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137059/the-singular-values-of-the-hilbert-matrix) matrices on Math Overflow. I don't think there is an explicit formula, but there are probably bounds or other known properties. However, I don't have a reference to suggest. It may be worth looking up articles about these matrices.